# 403 Forbidden using URL encoded on AS400

Tags: javascript, html, ibm-midrange

Get the error 403 Forbidden when I trying to use an encoded URL, for example, the original URL and working is

> http://myip.com/mypgm.pgm?USR=name&CTA=6822&VAL=1

but when I use

> http://myip.com/mypgm.pgm%3FUSR%3Dname%26CTA%3D6822%26VAL%3D1

I get the error, how can I allow the execution of an encoded URL in my httpd.conf? I am not using any mod_security.

I have to send the URL as parameter, that's why I am testing the URL in this way. I'm working over AS400.

Comment: only encode the data, not the ? and & symbols and the field names in the string.  I bet your encoding the entire query string... that's incorrect.  Encode each piece of data before building your query string.

/cgi-bin/mypgm?field1=<encoded_data_1>&field2=<encodeded_data_2>

Answer (score 1):

If the URL is sent encoded to a page as an URL-parameter (i.e. "http://some.url/?url=yourencodedurl"), you could decode the parameter ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter) for one way to get the argument) in the some.url page and then invoke after using `decodeURIComponent()`:

```
window.location = decodeURIComponent(argUrl); // get argUrl first as string
```

This:

> http://myip.com/mypgm.pgm%3FUSR%3Dname%26CTA%3D6822%26VAL%3D1

would then become

```
decodeURIComponent("http://myip.com/mypgm.pgm%3FUSR%3Dname%26CTA%3D6822%26VAL%3D1"):
```

> "http://myip.com/mypgm.pgm?USR=name&CTA=6822&VAL=1"

Comment: Thank you for your answer but actually that was not what I needed. I asking for options in the Apache .conf in order to allow encoded URLs.